# Capture Windows registered messages by name

Tags: windows, message, delphi-10.1-berlin

On Windows tablets there are two on screen keyboard apps (that I'm aware of), c:\program files\common files\microsoft shared\ink\tabtip.exe
 and C:\Windows\System32\OSK.exe.

I want to capture the messages that these apps send to my application when they are launched, placed on top of my app, and when they close.

Then I can check IsIconic as insurance to as much as possible know what state the keyboard is in so that I can adjust my app display accordingly.

Using spy++ I've captured the following messages for TabTip:

> <000050> 00130426 P message:0xC298 [Registered:"ImmersiveFocusNotification"] wParam:FFFFFFFC lParam:00000000
>
> <000051> 00130426 P message:0xC297 [Registered:"TipCloseMenus"] wParam:00000000 lParam:00000000
>
> <000052> 00130426 P message:0xC061 [Registered:"TabletInputPanelOpening"] wParam:00000000 lParam:00000000

I thought that there is a Windows API call that would allow me to register with the OS to receive these messages in my app's window procedure, or using a message handler proc to get the notification, but I can't seem to find it.

Although these messages show up in my app's message queue in spy++, I can't seem to identify them in my WindowProc, and Delphi won't allow me to specify a message handling proc for these message id's which are in the 49xxx range.

Does anyone know the way to register for these messages by name? I thought that was possible by taking a string like

> TabletInputPanelOpening

or

> TipCloseMenus

so that when the OS processes the message by that name my app can receive / process it?

Thanks.

**Update:** With an Application.OnMessage handler, I can receive the messages if I ignore the handle that the message is sent to. I'm assuming that this means that this is a broadcast message(?).

I still need to know how to register to receive messages that are:

> 1) Sent by PostMessage or SendMessage
>
> 2) Established with the system by using RegisterWindowMessage
>
> 3) Have a named constant that identifies the message, such as 'TipCloseMenus' or 'TaskbarCreated'

**Update #2:**
I found an old example that shows that RegisterWindowMessage and GetClipboardFormatName appear to use the same internal table for storing both registered window messages and clipboard formats. Calling GetClipboardFormatName with the TMsg.message as the parameter looks up the label for the messageid. So apparently to some extent these messages are stored in the same internal table. Here's some sample code to illustrate:

```
function GetRegisteredWindowMessageLabel(var Msg: TMsg): UnicodeString;
var
  ay: array[0..99] of Char;
  i: Integer;
begin
  Result := '';
  if (Msg.message <= $FFFF) and (Msg.message >= $C000) then
  begin
    i := GetClipboardFormatName(Msg.message,ay,Pred(SizeOf(ay)));
    if i > 0 then
      Result := StrPas(ay);
  end;
end;
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot write compile-time message handlers for registered messages, as they do not use static message IDs.  You must call `RegisterWindowMessage()` at runtime and then filter received messages using the registered IDs, eg:

```
var
  msgImmersiveFocusNotification: UINT = 0;
  msgTipCloseMenus: UINT = 0;
  msgTabletInputPanelOpening: UINT = 0;
  msgTaskbarCreated: UINT = 0;

procedure TMainForm:FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  msgImmersiveFocusNotification := RegisterWindowMessage('ImmersiveFocusNotification');
  msgTipCloseMenus := RegisterWindowMessage('TipCloseMenus');
  msgTabletInputPanelOpening := RegisterWindowMessage('TabletInputPanelOpening');
  msgTaskbarCreated := RegisterWindowMessage('TaskbarCreated');
end;

procedure TMainForm.WndProc(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  inherited;
  if (msgImmersiveFocusNotification <> 0) and (Message.Msg = msgImmersiveFocusNotification) then
  begin
    //...
  end
  else if (msgTipCloseMenus <> 0) and (Message.Msg = msgTipCloseMenus) then
  begin
    //...
  end
  else if (msgTabletInputPanelOpening <> 0) and (Message.Msg = msgTabletInputPanelOpening) then
  begin
    //...
  end
  else if (msgTaskbarCreated <> 0) and (Message.Msg = msgTaskbarCreated) then
  begin
    //...
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Does this apply to messages that an app other than mine has registered? All of the messages that I am seeking, such as "HOOKUTIL_MSG" (osx.exe) or "TabletInputPanelOpening" are from other apps that I'm not in control of. I was under the impression that RegisterWindowMessage was only applicable if I register my own custom message?

Comment: Registered messages are global within a desktop session. If multiple apps running in the same session register the same message, they receive the same ID number. This allows a registered message to be used for IPC. This is stated in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644947.aspx): "*The RegisterWindowMessage function is typically used to register messages for communicating between two cooperating applications. If two different applications register the same message string, the applications return the same message value.*"

Comment: Thanks Remy. I looked at the MSDN doc but somehow missed that. This works great for the TabTip keyboard from MSInk. OSK is another matter. I'm going to have to find another method for that, because I can't seem to catch the HOOKUTIL_MSG and SHELLHOOK messages that spy++ shows as being registered by OSK. Or perhaps I'm reading it wrong. Either way I don't receive them either in Application.OnMessage nor in the Application MainForm's custom WindowProc.

Comment: Where exactly are you seeing those messages? I don't see them, and cannot find any documentation or any online reference about them at all. Those don't look like OSK-related messages anyway.  What EXACTLY are you trying to achieve by receiving such messages?

Comment: My mainform allows for user input. With our current configuration if our app is displayed and one of the keyboards (TabTip,OSK) shows up on the tablet it covers our app. So the user could be attempting to enter text but can't see the target editor because it is obscured by the keyboard. What we want to do is detect when either keyboard is displayed on the tablet, and adjust the display characteristics of our app to cover the full screen in a tiled fashion, for ex. our app above the keyboard, which ususally displays on the bottom of the screen. So the user can see both.

Comment: If a keyboard app obscures your editor window, the user could just move the keyboard window out of the way. It is a free-floating window, after all.  Otherwise, your app could just monitor the keyboard windows, such as with `SetWinEventHook()`, and act accordingly, without having to receive messages directly from the keyboard apps.  The registered messages you are trying to handle are undocumented, and thus should not be considered reliable for external use.

Comment: Thanks Remy. Our app works in a real time, mission critical, life and death setting. Our users would maybe move the app around and size it once or twice to get it right with the keyboard, and then talk to their CIO about getting another vendor. Also they are extremely harried, so we do everything we can to automate as much of their workflow as possible so that they don't have to think about stupid stuff like screen behavior of multiple independent apps. I'll take a look at SetWinEventHook(), thanks for the pointer.

Comment: Have you considered having your app provide its own on-screen keyboard instead of using the OS keyboard apps?  Delphi has a [`TTouchKeyboard`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Touch.Keyboard.TTouchKeyboard) component, for instance. If you used OSK instead, you could [launch and position it manually](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24707902/how-to-position-the-on-screen-keyboard-window), at least.

Comment: That's a great idea Remy, thanks for that. However we'd still have to deal with launches of TabTip or OSK, right? So then wouldn't I have to find the keyboard app that is launched by the system, hide it or kill it, and make sure that mine is where I want it? We don't have control over the config of the user's tablet, so we're just trying to get along and play nice with what they already have. Your approach would be a LOT simpler. I just know that we'd still have to deal with the other keyboards.